# Python script to create Android/iOS strings from a .csv

Tags: python, beginner, csv, i18n

My script takes a CSV file of strings and then creates an XML file for Android and a .strings file to be used for iOS. It separates each locale meaning that a file will be created for each language.

This has come in handy so far, making localising mobile apps easier. However, I am always seeking feedback so let me know what you think.

## Input

The .csv is provided in the format: key, language1, language2

> ```
> key,en,ru
> welcome_message,hello,здравствуйте
> thank_you_message,thank you,спасибо
> goodbye_message,goodbye,До свидания
> ```

## Output

### XML - Android

en_strings.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<resources>
    <string name="welcome_message">hello</string>
    <string name="thank_you_message">thank you</string>
    <string name="goodbye_message">goodbye</string>
</resources>
```

ru_strings.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<resources>
    <string name="welcome_message">здравствуйте</string>
    <string name="thank_you_message">спасибо</string>
    <string name="goodbye_message">До свидания</string>
</resources>
```

### .Strings - iOS

en.strings

```xml
/*  */
"welcome_message" = "hello";

/*  */
"thank_you_message" = "thank you";

/*  */
"goodbye_message" = "goodbye";
```

ru.strings

```xml
/*  */
"welcome_message" = "здравствуйте";

/*  */
"thank_you_message" = "спасибо";

/*  */
"goodbye_message" = "До свидания";
```

At the moment I've just hardcoded the origin Strings.csv file and the user defines the target directory, this will be useful when integrating it into automatic builds etc.

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Script takes a csv and creates strings for Android (.xml) and iOS (.Strings).
# csv in the format [key, language1, langauge2 ......]
# usage - Python converter.py [FILEPATH]

import sys, os, getopt, csv, xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.dom import minidom

def prettify(elem):
    rough_string = ET.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="\t")

# Read in output directory
try:   
   sys.argv[1:] 
   fileDestination = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:  
   print "Error: Please supply an output directory."
   print "Usage: converter.py [FILEPATH]"
   sys.exit()  

# Create directory if it doesn't exists
if not os.path.exists(fileDestination):
    os.makedirs(fileDestination)

# Read from csv
f = open('Strings.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

# Determine the number of languages from the csv
line1 = csv_f.next()
numberOfLocales =  len(line1)

# Create strings for each language
for x in range(1, numberOfLocales):
    #Returns to the start of the csv and ignores the first line
    f.seek(0)
    csv_f.next()
    rowIndex = 0

    # Android xml
    resources = ET.Element("resources")

    # Create iOS strings file
    iOSFile = open(fileDestination+"/"+line1[x]+".Strings", "w+")

    for row in csv_f:
        ++rowIndex
        try:
            # Write string to xml
            ET.SubElement(resources, "string", name=row[0]).text = row[x].decode('utf-8')
            # Write string to iOS .Strings
            iOSFile.write("/*  */\n")
            iOSFile.write('"'+row[0]+'"'+ ' = ' + '"'+row[x]+'"' + ";\n")
            iOSFile.write("\n")
        except IndexError:
            f.seek(0)
            print "There is a problem with the csv file at row {}".format(rowIndex+1) + " with the language {}".format(line1[x])
            r = list(csv_f)
            print r[rowIndex]
            sys.exit()
    # Write to Android file
    androidFile = open(fileDestination+"/"+line1[x]+"_strings.xml", "w+")
    androidFile.write(prettify(resources).encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Non working code is off-topic:`++rowIndex`, incremeneting like that is not Python

Comment: `+` does nothing `++` does nothing twice -> (i.e. nothing)

Comment: Actually I think that is just a bug, upvoting now.

Comment: In my system(Windows7), I see that the ru resource files(ru.Strings and ru_strings.xml) are not saved correctly, and they are just empty files, and you should add a function call to `close()` to the file object to correctly save the resource files. BTW: the English files(en.Strings and en_strings.xml) are correctly saved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Python style for naming is `snake_case` for functions and variables, and `PascalCase` for classes. If you have constant variables (values don't change), they should be in `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE`.

You also shouldn't be importing multiple modules on one line, like you've done here:

```
import sys, os, getopt, csv, xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
```

These imports should be separated onto separate lines, as per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), Python's official style guide.

These comments at the very top of your file:

```
# Script takes a csv and creates strings for Android (.xml) and iOS (.Strings).
# csv in the format [key, language1, langauge2 ......]
# usage - Python converter.py [FILEPATH]
```

Should be converted into a docstring, like this:

```
"""
Script takes a csv and creates strings for Android (.xml) and iOS (.Strings).
csv in the format [key, language1, langauge2 ......]
usage - Python converter.py [FILEPATH]
"""
```

This is not how you should be opening files.

```
f = open('Strings.csv')
```

Rather, you should use a `with ... as ...` [context manager](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/). By using a context manager, you can ensure that the file is properly closed. Here's how you'd do that:

```
with open("Strings.csv") as f:
    ...
```

Finally, the below line does nothing.

```
++rowIndex
```

It should be changed to `row_index += 1`, if I understand your intent correctly.

Comment: Thanks Ethan, such a detailed answer! This is the first useful script I've written in Python, I appreciate the guidance!

Comment: @stepwise_refinement No problem. Always willing to help out! :)

Answer (score 5):

**If a value is there but nobody uses it, is it really there?**

A line confused me very much:

```
sys.argv[1:]
```

It does nothing, it evals a thing and then the value is discarded, you should remove it.

---

`ET` actually follows the official preferred name in the docs, well chosen!

**Is an error a success?**

Yes, in a philosophical sense, you learn from your error, but in code it is not.

```
print "Error: Please supply an output directory."
print "Usage: converter.py [FILEPATH]"
sys.exit()
```

Please use `sys.exit(1)` to signal error.

**Enumerate and `for item in iterable`**

In python explicit indexing is frowned upon:

```
for x in range(1, numberOfLocales):
```

It is better to use `enumerate`:

```
for locale, index in enumerate(line1):
    # Do stuff
```

Also here:

```
for row, row_index in enumerate(csv_f):
    # ...
```

So you can avoid manual incrementing.

Comment: Since the OP noted this might get used for automated builds, I'd make note of the fact that using `sys.exit(1)` will be vital for communicating a failure back to a build script or server.

Comment: Thanks for the response Caridorc! I will definitely implement your suggestions.